# Is it possible to manage a hierarchical product structure in SBT which has more than just one level?

Tags: sbt

We have a multi module project consisting of two modules, modA and modB.

modA depends on modB.

modB in turn depends on a list of libraries (libA and libB) where we also have the source code. This sources have already been adapted by us.

At last, libB and libC are independend from each other, but depend on a third library, libC.

What I *want* to have is a setup, where the three libraries (which are in principle also a multi-module SBT project) can just be "included" in the top level project.

The point here is also that these libraries can be re-used for other projects, too, so the changed sources should not belong to this super project only.

Currently I tried to solve it by including the library as GIT submodule.
Unfortunately SBT does not (seem to) support hierarchical sub modules, so I cannot really just have a second, also multi-module SBT file for all libraries which just gets included in the "super-super" project.

This current setup is clearly not the SBT way.
What *is* the intended method of solving this?
Just adapting the library separately and re-using it just as JAR file in the super project is possible, but clumsy, because the using project(s) are the main reason to hack the library, so it would be nice if this works in a smooth way.

Comment: AFAIK you can't have nested sbt projects. Using a jar dependency is the way I've done this.

Comment: This is possible, the problem is that changing the library for the application using it becomes more cumbersome, esp. for testing. Yes, I can use publishLocal, but again - this is cumbersome, and I wanted to know if there is an easier way.