# How to use sbt to create 1 sub-project from 2 packages?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I defined 2 sub-projects to create 2 jars for 2 packages. Can I create 1 sub-projects with 2 packages below? thanks

```
//subproject for domain package so that AWS lambda can consume the jar
lazy val domainProject = (project in file("domain"))
  .enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(assemblyJarName in assembly := "domainPackage.jar")

//subproject for util package so that AWS lambda can consume the jar
lazy val utilProject = (project in file("util"))
  .enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(assemblyJarName in assembly := "utilPackage.jar")
  .dependsOn(domainProject)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the desired result is?

Answer (score 0):

You have already a root project which aggregates domainProject and utilProject.
If you want to have a deeper project hierarchy, then I also asked for that (in [Is it possible to manage a hierarchical product structure in SBT which has more than just one level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510141/is-it-possible-to-manage-a-hierarchical-product-structure-in-sbt-which-has-more?noredirect=1#comment72177751_42510141)) - this is not possible....